# angular 2 formControlName directive

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a scenario where i have a custom directive on the input element which listens on the focus event on that input and store that elementRef in one service.

```
  <md-input-container>
      <textarea mdInput formControlName="content"
              [readonly]="!editable" mdTextareaAutosize 
              inniNativeInputFocusDirective> 
      </textarea>
  </md-input-container>
```

Basically i want to track the last focused input element.

Now i have another sidebar showing the list of items. Now when i click on that item then the last focused input element value should be appended with the item value.

now in my component when i update the value like this.

```
this.renderer.setProperty(this.lastFocusedElementRef.nativeElement, 'value', newValue);
```

but with this the form model is not updated. formControlName directive is not updating the model from the input value.

Comment: What have you done to check 1. that you track correctly the last input 2. newValue also has been set correctly ?

Comment: Can you please provide us with a reproduction?